# jQuery function repeats, after re attaching the event handler because new html is displayed

Tags: jquery, html

So I am executing a `$.post()` to get some html code returned from a php script which accesses an SQLite database

I need to attach a click event to an edit button that shows when the page loads the new html, so I attach the click event after the `.empty().html()` then if the user edits the record by submitting the data it does another `$.post()` to reresh the screen and show the new data, so I attach the click event handler again, because if I don't the edit buttons on the page don't work anymore because they weren't there when the `.click()' was attached the first time

BUT when I do this and edit multiple records it runs multiple times (I alert the record ID each time it does a `$.post()` and it does it the same amount of times as edits I have clicked, I have seen posts about how `.live()` can cause this issue and people suggest binding click which is what I am doing, so I don't see what's happening...here is the code

```
$(".edit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $realTipID=this.id;
    $.post("ajax.php",{action:'getTip',tipID:$realTipID},function(data){
            $("#editTip_div").css("display","block");
            $("#editText").empty().val(unEscapeSpecialChars(data));//puts the data that is currently in the DB into a textarea to be editted
            $("#edit_tip").click(function(e){
            $.post("ajax.php",{action:'editTip',tipID:$realTipID,editText:escapeSpecialChars($("#editText").val())},function(data){

            if (data=="1")  {//check tosee that the update of the SQL table worked
                e.preventDefault();//tried this because someone suggested it in another StackOverflow post
                $(".edit").unbind('click');//and this
                $realTipID='';
                $("#editText").val('');
                $("#editTip_div").css("display","none");
                $('.result[id|='+$issueID+']').click();//refreshes the <div> with the content, includes this $(".edit").click() event 
            if (data=="0")  {//or failed
                alert("record not written, could be that there are quotes in the text, please remove, quotes, apostraphes, and ticks (`) as they will cause the line to fail"); 
            }

                                                        });
        });
        $("#cancel_edit").click(function()  {
            $("#editText").val('');
            $("#editTip_div").css("display","none");
                                                                });
        });

});
```

Comment: I only used php because I thought you had to have 3 tags, oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're setting multiple event handlers on the same element.  Does this help?
 edit: sorry, that should have been:

```
$(".edit").unbind().click(function(e){
```

Edited from:

```
$("#cancel_edit").unbind().click(function()
```

Comment: so I added that and it still does it, I got 2 alerts after making 2 edits and 3 alerts after making 3 edits

Comment: I edited my response.  You should unbind the .edit handler, not the #cancel_edit one

Comment: ok so I did in the first place because I knew it wasn't the cancel that was the issue, and then when it didnt work I tried just the .edit and still no go

Comment: I think I found it one second

Comment: you were SUPER CLOSE, but I will give you props since you are the only one who answered, it was the 

`$("#edit_tip").unbind().click(function(){`

Comment: Ha sorry about the mistaken identification.  Glad you found it.